# I have a simple/static CSS which I am trying to convert to responsive

Tags: css, responsive-design, responsive

I have following simple/static CSS which I wish to convert to responsive CSS for better look and display on different screen sizes. Can some one help?

```
#container {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 950px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  border: 1px solid #9F9F9F;
  background: #FFFDFD;
}

#container .content {
  float: right;
  width: 710px;
  border-left: 1px solid #9F9F9F;
  padding: 5px;
}

#container .menu {
  float: left;
  width: 210px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

Comment: look into bootstrap

Comment: Just because you *can* write your selectors and property-declarations on a single line - giving a 'three-line CSS file' - doesn't mean you *should*, given that readability is more important than brevity (until you minify for gzipping).

Comment: Incidentally: "*I wish to convert to responsive CSS for better look.*" First: define "*better*." Second: what have you attempted? What exactly do you want us to help you with? Have you looked at, or learned about, [CSS Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) or [CSS Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), both of which should help you to write a responsive layout. While we're happy to help you with your code we're not willing to write your code for you.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
    #container {
        display: flex;
        align-items: stretch;
        padding:10px;
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 950px;
        margin:50px auto;
        border:1px solid #9F9F9F; 
        background: #FFFDFD;
   }
    #container .content {
        flex: 70%;
        max-width: 70%;
        order: 0;
    }

    #container .menu {
        flex: 30%;
        max-width: 30%;
        order: 1;
    }
```

Comment: "*Try this*" - why? What does it do? How does it work? What problem does it solve? How does your answer work? How, to be clear, is the OP - or any future visitor - supposed to learn from your answer?

Comment: He wanted help to solve problem. If he needs any explanation then he can write a comment in my answer. If he is happy with the solution then he would ask no more question. And you don't need to comment and cast downvote here. Thank you